# How to change SlidingWindow to seconds in AppMetrics

Tags: c#, metrics

in the [docu](https://alhardy.github.io/app-metrics-docs/api/App.Metrics.ReservoirSampling.SlidingWindow.DefaultSlidingWindowReservoir.html) it says

> A Reservoir implementation backed by a sliding window that stores only the measurements made in the last N seconds (or other time unit).

But I can only specify the datasize

```
public DefaultSlidingWindowReservoir(int sampleSize)
```

How can i change the sliding window to check only the last 5 seconds?